# how to share volume between Docker in Docker on the same host

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I am running a Jenkins cluster where in the Master and Slave, both are running as a Docker containers, managed by `K8s`. So I run a job from Jenkins, a pod gets created which in turn creates a container and the Job runs.

To allow Jenkins to be able to spawn inner container from the build agent container, I have mounted the docker.sock from the host to the Jenkins Pod `templated`:
[image: k8s volume]

For certain jobs we need to spawn another container inside the build agent container, here lies the problem, from the outer container (build agent) we would have cloned the git `repo` where few files are needed for the inner container (spawned container), we cannot copy them as Docker container uses the parent HOST's Docker daemon, how can i mount the volume from outer container to inner container ? Container and pods names are dynamic.
Is there any workaround, any help will be highly appreciated.